# Probability that number of Sundays is different from the number of Mondays

Tags: probability

Choose a number $n$ at random from the set $\{1,2,3,.....,100 \}$ . Choose one of the first seven days of the year $2014$ at random and consider $n$ consecutive days starting from chosen day. What is the probability that among the chosen $n$ days , the  number of Sundays is different from the number of Mondays ?

How should I proceed in this question. Every combination of one of first $7$ days of $2014$ and value of $n$ makes for different case. So how to narrow down cases to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If it so happens that $n$ is divisible by $7$, then the question is easy; every day will occur with equal frequency. This also suggests that all you *really* need to look at is $n \bmod 7$. Focus on the 7 cases of what $n \bmod 7$ can be, and within each one, you'll be able to partition the days of the week into "ones where there will be a different number of Sundays and Mondays" and "ones where there won't." It will be somewhat tedious, but it's not too many cases that way.